# Determinant of any squared submatrix of incidence matrix of any graph is 0, $(-2)^i$ or $2^i$?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-graph-theory

Why the below proposition is true?

> For any graph, determinant of any submatrix of its incidence matrix is 0, $(-2)^i$ or $2^i$. ($i \in \mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: What is $i$ and what kind of graph is it? Let $G$ be a directed graph with $i$ nodes and each node is connected to itself only. Then the determinant of its incidence matrix is $1$, which is neither $0,(-2)^i$ nor $2^i$.

Comment: What reason do you have for believing this proposition?

Comment: @GerryMyerson unfortunately I have no idea to prove it. But it's my home work and I couldn't solve it yet.

Comment: Maybe the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301913/a-property-of-incidence-matrix-of-a-graph by Chris Godsil will be useful.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/94400/11619) shows that all powers of $\pm 2$ occur. The graphs relevant to the matrices of that question are unions of disjoint cycles. I don't know about the other direction. May be the general case can be reduced to this?

Comment: @GerryMyerson so helpful comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so helpful comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The incidence matrix $B$ of a graph has its rows indexed by vertices and columns by edges; its $ij$-entry is 1 if the $i$-th vertex is on the $j$-th edge, otherwise it's 0. In general it is is not square. It is true that the determinant of a square submatrix of the incidence matrix of a graph is $0$ or $\pm 2^k$ for some $k$. It has the important consequence that if $b$ is an integer vector and $Bx=b$, then $2x$ is an integer vector, this plays a role in some combinatorial optimization problems on graphs.

I offer some hints towards a proof. Suppose $M$ is a square submatrix of $B$.
If a row or column of $M$ is zero, we're done. Similarly if a row or column has exactly one non-zero entry, by induction. So each column of $M$ must have exactly two non-zero entries. Now you can argue that $M$ must be the incidence matrix of a cycle, and then compute its determinant.